# 500 server error in MAMP on jQuery AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mamp

I'm running MAMP locally and trying to use jQuery's `$.post()` to send some data to a PHP script, but when the function fires I get a 500 error: `POST http://localhost:8888/app_name/php/add_new_class.php 500 (Internal Server Error)`

I'm fairly new to PHP but relatively familiar with basic ajax. Am I doing something wrong in the code? Is it a server configuration/permissions thing? Is there any more info I can provide to help? Thanks in advance.

Relevant HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="addclass" >Add Class</a></li>
    <li><a href="#rubric">Rubric</a></li>
</ul>
```

Relevant JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#addclass', addNewClass);
});

function addNewClass() {
    var newClass = prompt('Enter new class name:').trim()
    if ( (newClass != null) && (newClass != '') ) {
        $.post('php/add_new_class.php', {post_class_name:newClass}, function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    } else {
        alert('You didn\'t enter any text. Please enter a valid class name.');
    }
}
```

Relevant PHP:

```
<?php

require_once 'db_connect.php';

$class_name = $_POST['post_class_name'];

$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO classes (class_name) VALUES ('%s');",
    mysql_real_escape_string($class_name));

mysql_query($query)
    or die(echo mysql_error());

echo 'success';

?>
```

**Edit:**

It was a simple PHP error on my part. Being new to PHP, I wasn't aware that a 500 internal server error could indicate this, nor that a helpful description could be found in the error log. The error was in

```
mysql_query($query)
    or die(echo mysql_error());
```

That `echo` wasn't necessary in the `die` statement, and caused it to fail.

Comment: Definitely going to be a php error. i'd suggest trying to get a more meaningful php error.

Comment: Have you checked wheter the 500 HTTP error occures on other pages?

Comment: sinaneker -- Other pages seem to work just fine, including some little test PHP scripts.

Comment: Check the error log …

Comment: CBroe-- Thanks. I'm new to PHP and MAMP, and didn't think to check the error log. Turns out PHP didn't like the `echo` in the `die` handler for the `mysql_query`. I'm also pretty new to stackoverflow--should I make that an answer and mark it as correct, or something? Thanks again.